# My html logo can not work in email

Tags: php, html, css, email

I have tried to code a email for resetting password for users, and want to include my website's logo in the email. The logo can appear correctly when I open the mail through iphone, but it appears nothing when I open through the website yahoo.com and login to the mail

here is my mail :

```
$message='
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>lsere Message</title></head>
    <body>
    <header style="border-bottom:2px solid #f0f0f0;padding-bottom:20px;"><div style="margin-top:15px;
        box-shadow:1px 1px 10px gray;
        border-radius:5px;
        width:100px;
        margin-left:15px;
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:5px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
        color:white;
        font-size:25px;
        font-weight:bold;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#a13030, #780000); 
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#a13030,#780000); 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#a13030,#780000); 
        background: linear-gradient(#a13030,#780000); 
        ">
        L\'sere
    </div>
    </header>
    <div>
    Reset Lsere account password<br>
    <div><a href="http://localhost/social_network/reset_password.php">Click here to reset your password</a></div>
    <div>Or you can enter your six digits confirmation code and continue on the lese page</div>
    <div>Your confirmation code is <span style="background:#f0f0f0; padding:2px;">'.$confirmation_code.' <span></div>

    </div>


    </body>

    </html>';   

    $headers = 'From: kesongxie646@gmail.com\n';

    $headers.='MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers.='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
```

Comment: Do you really think you can use all the CSS you want in an email ? Yahoo mail and a lot of webmails can't handle complicated CSS properties.

Comment: you are sending people a link that starts with `http://localhost` ? really?

Comment: I still text my website in local computer @Banana

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: im not quite sure if its relevant anymore, but is it possible that you have tried reading the mail using Internet Explorer? you might need to add the `-ms-` prefix : `background: -ms-linear-gradient(#a13030,#780000);`

Comment: also, since your document is pretty simple, you might want to change the `<header>` tag to `<div>` it will produce same results but will be compatible with wider range of browsers

Answer (score 0):

Your Iphone has extended support for complicated CSS but just like Vincent said, webmail doesn't offer extended support for such complicated support, when you come to think of it, I know browsers that will not support that.

So you better give up the CSS version and start thinking about actually inserting an image.

Comment: Anytime :) If the entire purpose of this is to transform your image intro a code, you can always convert your image to Data-URI Base-64 Code. Here is a website that can do that for you http://duri.me/